# Lista encadeada de strings (vetor de caracteres) em C

Tags: c, string, lista, lista-encadeada, caracteres

Eu estou realizando um trabalho para faculdade, e é basicamente sobre **tabela Hash**. No trabalho, eu tenho que fazer a tabela Hash de um **n** strings, por exemplo. Ao invés de fazer um array de array de caracteres (no caso, um array de strings), eu gostaria de implementar uma lista encadeada, porque sendo assim no final eu poderia adicionar mais strings na lista e na tabela hash.

Porém, estou tendo dificuldades em implementar uma lista encadeada de strings, pois não sei como a "célula", por exemplo, pode armazenar um vetor (no caso, a string, vetor de caracteres).

A ajuda que peço aqui então, é me ajudar a transformar o seguinte código que fiz (que gera palavras aleatórias de tamanho aleatórios) em uma lista encadeada. Basicamente, inserir a variável **word[i]** na lista encadeada.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main() {

    srand(time(NULL));
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    int strQty = 100;
    int strLimit = 11;

    int ascMin = 97;
    int ascMax = 122;

    char words[strQty][strLimit];

    // Gerando strings aleatorias
    int i, j;
    int size, letter;

    for (i=0; i<strQty; i++) {

        // Tamanho da palavra words[i] -- de 1 a 10.
        size = rand()%(10)+1;

        for (j=0; j<size; j++) {

            letter = rand()%(ascMax-ascMin)+ascMin;
            words[i][j] = (char)letter;
        }

        // Indica o fim da string
        words[i][size] = '\0'; 
    }

    // Lendo strings geradas
    for (i=0; i<strQty; i++) {

        printf("Posição [%03d], tamanho [%02d], Palavra [%s]: ", i, strlen(words[i]), words[i]);
        for (j=0; j<strlen(words[i]); j++) {
                printf("%c", words[i][j]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

No mais, aguardo as respostas e desde já agradeço a ajuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O código está gerando a palavra em uma variável `char word` e está sendo passado para a função `insereLista`.

Também foi adicionada uma função de imprimir a lista encadeada, acredito que você consiga adaptar para seu objetivo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <locale.h>

#define STRLIMIT 10
typedef struct lista{
    char word[STRLIMIT];
    struct lista* prox;
}Lista;

Lista* insereLista(Lista* l, char word[], int size){
    Lista* novo = (Lista*)malloc(sizeof(Lista));
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<size; i++) {
        novo->word[i] = word[i];
    }
    novo->word[size] = '\0';
    novo->prox = l;
    return novo;
}

void imprimeLista(Lista* l){
    printf("---- lista -----\n");
    do{
        printf("%s\n", l->word);
        l= l->prox;
    }while(l != NULL);
}

int main() {

    srand(time(NULL));
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    int strQty = 100;
    int strLimit = 11;

    int ascMin = 97;
    int ascMax = 122;

    //char words[strQty][strLimit];


    // Gerando strings aleatorias
    int i, j;
    int size, letter;

    Lista* l = NULL; //Lista encadeada
    for (i=0; i<strQty; i++) {

        // Tamanho da palavra words[i] -- de 1 a 10.
        size = rand()%(10)+1;
        char word[strLimit];
        for (j=0; j<size; j++) {

            letter = rand()%(ascMax-ascMin)+ascMin;
            word[j] = (char)letter;
        }

        // Indica o fim da string
        word[size] = '\0';
        l = insereLista(l, word, size);
    }
    imprimeLista(l);

    // Lendo strings geradas
    /*
    for (i=0; i<strQty; i++) {

        printf("Posição [%03d], tamanho [%02d], Palavra [%s]: ", i, strlen(words[i]), words[i]);
        for (j=0; j<strlen(words[i]); j++) {
                printf("%c", words[i][j]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
    */
}
```

Para inserir no fim:

```
Lista* insereFim(Lista* l, char word[], int size){
    Lista* novo = (Lista*)malloc(sizeof(Lista));
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<size; i++) {
        novo->word[i] = word[i];
    }
    novo->word[size] = '\0';
    novo->prox = NULL;

    //Se for o primeiro elemento
    if( l==NULL)
        return novo;

    //Insere no fim
    Lista* aux = l;
    while(aux->prox!=NULL)
        aux=aux->prox;
    aux->prox = novo;
    return l;
}
```